# View Report in XBAP Partial Trust

Tags: reporting, xbap

I Have a Problem for view Application Reports in XBAP Partail Trust . because of using xbap in Partial trust, can not use windowsFormsHost.
Is there is a way to view report in XBAP Application? (rdlc || Crystal || etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution i found to use in my application is:

1. Create SSRS Report
2. Create 3rd party asp.net App. to Shiw reports
3. Show Asp.Net Pages(Taht Showing report) in XBAP app.